# Append array of values inside array - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, foreach, each

I have an array of arrays with values that I need to append to `<div>`, but somehow `.each()` function of **underscore.js** doesn't work as expected..

**array**: `var arr = [['20-12-2012', 'Text'],['01-02-2012', 'Text2'], ...];`

how my function looks:

```
_(arr).each(function (row, i) {
   $('<div class="wrap"></div>').appendTo('#mainWrap');

   _(row).each(function (line) {
       $('<span>' + line + '</span>').appendTo('.wrap');
   });
});
```

but result is that both two first arrays inside main array are applied to first `.wrap`:

**result**:

```
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>20-12-2012</span><span>Text</span>
    <span>01-02-2012</span><span>Text2</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>01-02-2012</span><span>Text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

but I **expect** it to be as:

```
<div id="mainWrap">
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>20-12-2012</span><span>Text</span>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <span>01-02-2012</span><span>Text2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Store the wrap element in the each loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select which `.wrap` you need to append to. `.wrap` will select all the element with class `wrap` that has already been appended and it appends the span to all of them hence you see this behavior.

Try:

```
_(arr).each(function (row, i) {
    var $wrap =  $('<div class="wrap"></div>').appendTo('#mainWrap'); //save the wrap here

   _(row).each(function (line) {
       $('<span>' + line + '</span>').appendTo($wrap); //append to the wrap that was created in the previous loop.
   });
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/V58GN/)**

If you have too many items to be appended consider appending to DOM element in the end rather than in the loop, save them to a temp jquery object and in the end append to the main element, more like this.

```
var arr = [['20-12-2012', 'Text'],['01-02-2012', 'Text2']], $main = $('<div/>');

_(arr).each(function (row, i) {
  var $wrap =  $('<div class="wrap"></div>').appendTo($main);

   _(row).each(function (line) {
       $('<span>' + line + '</span>').appendTo($wrap);
   });
});
$('#mainWrap').append($main.html()); //Append to DOM now. For replace use .html
```